# Insert incoming data from third party api to aws mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kinesis

I am a fresher so i am new to aws so kindly forgive if its a noob question. My manager asked me to implement a solution where a third party will provide an **api** and I will have to insert live incoming data into our aws MySQL database. I tried to look for ways to achieve this and found `aws kinesis` service could be of use. I am not sure if it could be used for my application.
Do let me how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Does the third party API implement the Producer/Consumer or Publisher/Subscriber pattern?

Comment: @Maurice Actually I don't know yet. Can I implement both of these using kinesis?

Comment: Kinesis is just a way to temporarily store varying amounts of data and make the accessible to other services, by itself it won't write data to your table or query an API. You could use it to buffer data, but in that case SQS is probably cheaper as a queue. There's too little information here about the technologies being used and the functional requirements.

Comment: @Maurice Forgive me if I didn't mention it clearly. I am looking for something like, connect kinesis data stream to third-party service using some API, then send data from kinesis to aws rds. I have implemented kinesis to aws rds part for some different work. I only need guidance in connecting third-party service to kinesis for listening to real-time data.

Comment: So what you want to build is a Kinesis producer. That's essentially a piece of software running the Kinesis Producer Library (KPL) to send data to Kinesis. You can run that e.g. inside of a container which connects to the API, requests the data and sends it to Kinesis through the KPL, but how you'd build the container depends on the API and the pattern it implements.